# Forcing a generic parameter

Tags: f#

I have the following issue:
I have 2 types that are paremterized and that should work with a generic function if both types have the same type parameters

```
type A<'a> = A of 'a
type C<'a> = C of 'a

let inline save ((A a) :A<'a>) ((C c):C<'a>) = saveToDB (a :: c :: []) |> ignore

save (A 1) (C 2)
save (A "1") (C "2")
```

Now imagine a function that should execute the `save` but with different types which will be instantiated via some indicator

```
let inline save indicator (otherval:C<'a>) =
    match indicator with
    | "i" -> save (A 1) otherval
    | "s" -> save (A "s") otherval
```

In this case I get an error on `| "s" -> adder (A "s") otherval` saying that `otherval` should be of type `C<int>`

Any idea on how to approach this?

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: You can't have a function of a type that is determined at runtime. Type must be known at compile time. If you need to do this, you have to erase the type (i.e. use `obj`). Perhaps if you described the larger problem someone could suggest a better approach.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin imagine a webservice entry point that first instantiates an type by reading from a DB and then applies some data to this new type. The instantiation happens via some indicator that defines which kind of parameters this types should be instantiated with. Now I want to make sure that the data and the new type have the same paramter

Comment: So... If you somehow determined which type to create, can't you use the same mechanism to determine which function to call?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin uhhh - yeah sure. BUT apart from the type signature those functions would be exactly the same. So I'd have to create lots and lots of boilerplate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on Julien Roncaglia's answer, this method should at least be type-safe because we are using when guards:

```
let inline save ((A a) :A<'a>) ((C c):C<'a>) = saveToDB (a :: c :: []) |> ignore

let boxToGenericC<'a, 'b> (c: C<'a>) =
    unbox<C<'b>>(box(c))

let save1 indicator (otherval:C<'a>) =
    match indicator with
    | "i" when typeof<'a> = typeof<System.Int32> -> save (A 1) (boxToGenericC<'a, int> otherval)
    | "s" when typeof<'a> = typeof<string>-> save (A "s") (boxToGenericC<'a, string> otherval)
```

and attemping to do `save1 "s" (C 1)` gives a pattern match failure.

Answer (score 2):

While it might not be a "clean" design (And I don't see one without changing your specification) you can just tell the type system to stop caring :

```
let inline firstval indicator:A<'a> =
    let boxed =
        match indicator with
        | "i" -> box (A 1)
        | "s" -> box (A "s")

    unbox<A<'a>> boxed

let inline save2 indicator (otherval:C<'a>) =
    save (firstval indicator) otherval

save2 "i" (C 2)

save2 "s" (C "2")
```

It works but you lose some checking:

```
save2 "s" (C 1)
```

> Unable to cast object of type 'A`1[System.String]' to type 'A`1[System.Int32]'.